# How to create a permanent QR Code from app inventor

Tags: qr-code, app-inventor

I have a trouble. In my project I need to use my cell phone, scan a QR Code to enter in App Inventor, do some things there and then send to my arduino. It all feels good, but in order to be pratical I'm thinking to create a permanent QR Code from App Inventor. I already found a QR Code but is valid only a few times. I'm searching for something that is permanent.

[image]

Here's the QR Code, but as you can see it's only for testing, it isn't permanent.

Comment: QR codes are static images which do not have an expiration date. If you're creating a QR code that lasts just 2 hours, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Do you really need to use App Inventor? Can't you use Android Studio?

Comment: App Inventor were the easier way that I found to communicate with my arduino program, and to add I've no experience with another programs like Android Studio.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzMaBceluZE have you tried following this link? This guy shows how to create QR codes in App Inventor, which I just scanned, and it's still valid

Comment: How do you know your QR code has expired? Can't you read it? Maybe post some screenshots of your code. It would be easier to debug and find the problem

Comment: This guy created a QR Code in App Inventor, but I just need to find a way to create a QR Code to scan and opens the App Inventor in my cell phone.

Comment: I put a screenshots, I hope it can help

Comment: Show me how you create a QR code. That's what I meant with screenshots to see if you are setting an expiration date in the QR code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run your aia project in Companion mode on your phone. You should compile your project and then install the apk to your device. No QR needed. If you need more help I suggest you try on the
[App Inventor community](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/)